# Powershell gets HTML instead of PDF from PDF link

Tags: powershell, pdf, invoke-webrequest

I'm attempting to use Invoke-WebRequest to download a freely-available PDF. My URL points to a PDF, and the Get request made in-browser for my PDF points to my URL. I attempted

`Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/gec3.12537" -outfile "file.pdf"`

And got HTML instead. I tried adding `-MaximumRedirection 2` and still got HTML. Changing redirection to 0 or 1 only produced errors.

This seems to happen with every link I attempt at that web domain.

Comment: Potential self-answer: changing the url from "doi/pdf" to "doi/pdfdirect" seems to have worked, which I only found out by reading the JS in the DOM very closely. This still seems odd to me, so I'll keep the question open for now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that url does not return the PDF per se, but a HTML age that most likely uses [PDF.JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF.js) or a variatione thereof to display the document inside the browser.

I don't know the site, but it seems you already have found a way to download the actual PDF file directly yourself.